# PHP: How to run sampling profiler in production?

Tags: php, performance, profiling, production-environment

**Production environment:** A load balancer / HTTP reverse proxy in front of cluster of worker machines running Apache 2.2 with `mod_php` 5.3 on 64 bit Linux. All worker machines are running identical fully custom PHP code and speak to single backend PostgreSQL database. The PHP code is optimized to spend CPU over talking to the database. The database machine has been verified to still have lots of idle.

**What I'm looking for:** sampling profiler that can attach to PHP process by PID and periodically stop the process (e.g. with `SIGSTOP`), collect PHP stack via memory inspection and the continue the process (e.g. with `SIGCONT`). The stopping period should be adjustable but I think stopping interval should be around 1-10 ms.

A single worker machine PHP process is expected to run a single request always in less than 100 ms. I'm mostly interested collecting profile data for those processes that take more than 100 ms. The best case scenario would be a sampling profiler that would be notified at the start of the request and if the PHP process handling the request is still running 100 ms later, start collecting samples at 1 ms intervals. This way any normally running process would be run to the end without interrupts and I would still get profiles for problematic cases.

**Does this kind of sampling profiler for PHP exist?** The intent is to not use instrumenting profiler because the overhead is too high and the instrumentation messes the statistics (been there, done that).

I'm already aware of XHProf and Xdebug but as far as I know, both are instrumenting profilers and affect the actual opcodes of PHP program. I'd highly prefer something that runs the normal PHP opcodes instead.

The closest I know would work is to run PHP code with HipHop and use sampling profiler for C/C++ code but I'm not yet ready to port the software to HipHop. And in that case, the profiling result would be representative only for HipHop, not for mod_php.

Comment: Note to self: it could be possible to combine http://inventorsparadox.blogspot.fi/2012/02/how-to-dump-php-stack-from-gdb.html and http://poormansprofiler.org/ to create a tool for this...

Comment: It seems that XHprof support sampling but documentation is very poor and sample rate is fixed as 100 ms which is a bit rough: http://php.net/manual/en/function.xhprof-sample-disable.php

Comment: Did you ever find a decent solution to this? I've found myself with a similar need (and, coincidentally, an almost identical setup to the one you describe)

Comment: I haven't found anything usable. I currently believe that the best method is to combine the parts from my first comment.

Comment: I found that the overhead of starting up gdb in my post (http://inventorsparadox.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-dump-php-stack-from-gdb.html) is somewhat significant when we run it on our production servers (which has about 100 PHP processes). It causes slowdowns during high CPU load situations so I use it sparingly. I read the poormansprofiler.org, but find myself unable to understand awk codes. The concept is nice though. On the other hand, xhprof looks promising - have you tried it ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake of not reading fully before commenting.. forget about my xhprof comment. Collecting samples in 1 ms intervals? I think you're asking too much for a non real time OS. Every request completed under 100 ms with RDBMS access ? A single sector magnetic disk seek could cost you 10ms. So ten sector scattered read could cost you .. 100 ms, assuming data is not already in disk cache. So my first guess is you might want to use explicit data cache (such as apc or memcache), or use in-memory database, or might even use SSD for storage, that could drive down response time variation.

Comment: We're already running the database on Intel 320 series SSDs (RAID 1) so the disk latency is not an issue. Usually talking to RDBMS takes around 5-20 ms per request including opening the connection to RDBMS. Usually the request latency issues are caused by inefficient PHP code looping over complex in-memory structures constructed from data loaded from RDBMS. The fix in such cases is to implement the same logic with more performing algorithm which usually is way more complex to implement. The idea is to avoid implementing complex algorithms until really needed.

Comment: @YudhiWidyatama: poormansprofiler.org example code uses awk for converting from multiline stack trace output to single line presentation. It uses regex `/Thread/` to detect start of "next" stack trace because it's designed to collect one trace per thread. Then it just sorts and counts all identical stack traces (sampling profiler part). Sampling does not need to be strict either (e.g. every 1ms), the sampling interval just must be independent from the code being sampled. Random sampling latency between 1-10 ms should be just fine.

Comment: Note that to get PHP stack trace without having `xdebug` extension already loaded, you have to do things like this: https://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace.php

Comment: Also see https://aurelien-riv.github.io/php/2019/12/07/which-function-php-executing.html

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33067388/334451

Answer (score 2):

Although XHProf **does** add overhead to the request if it's enabled (via the function called, not just having the extension enabled), it varies depending on which flags you use. I measured this recently and found that having only XHPROF_FLAGS_MEMORY is the best option for minimal overhead:

http://rpubs.com/msonnabaum/xhprof_overhead

I just run XHProf on a small number of requests like so:

```
<?php
function xhprof_enabled() {
  if (mt_rand(1, 300) == 1) {
    xhprof_enable(XHPROF_FLAGS_MEMORY);
  }
}
```

But unlike xdebug, simply having the extension enabled doesn't seem to add any overhead at all.

Comment: Afaik XHProf doesn't even give you a complete stack (only "we are currently in this function, no idea why") and therefore does not fulfill the requirements.

Comment: @AndreKR once you know the function you can put debug_backtrace into your code. This is a minor issue :)

Answer (score -1):

I would not run any profiler tools on a production environment. Test servers are made to run profilers and load test.

Comment: On the contrary, that's exactly what facebook built [XhProfLive for: profiling production](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=62667953919).  Not everyone needs this, and for very small projects I'd agree with you.  But for large projects, profiling production is valuable.