# How to dump PHP backtrace on live running script in lldb?

Tags: php, debugging, gdb, lldb, debug-symbols

I'm playing around with [LLDB (debugger)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLDB_(debugger)) and I did the following experiment.

1. Run PHP script as:

   ```
   php -r "sleep(1000);"
   ```

   or:

   ```
   php -r "function r(){sleep(1000);}r();"
   ```
2. On another console, I've called directly `zif_debug_backtrace()` from `lldb`:

   ```
   echo 'call (void)zif_debug_backtrace()' | lldb -p $(pgrep -fn php)
   ```

Above worked, however the process stopped with the following warning:

```
Warning: sleep() expects at most 2 parameters, 1606408648 given in Command line code on line 1
Call Stack:
    0.0016     235152   1. {main}() Command line code:0
    0.0021     235248   2. sleep(1000) Command line code:1
```

I'm not quite sure why the script had to stop and what I need to do to achieve transparency (without affecting the script)?

P.S. The same happening when calling `zif_debug_print_backtrace()` and when calling `custom_backtrace()` it is showing: `Backtrace null function called`. I'm using `xdebug` if that change anything.

Maybe I need to call a different function like `zend_fetch_debug_backtrace` (see: `image dump symtab`)? Or use the right arguments, if so, which one?

I'm only interested in `lldb`/`gdb` solutions in order to print the backtrace.

---

Similar approach works in Ruby, e.g.:

1. Run: `ruby -e 'sleep 1000'`.
2. In another terminal: `echo 'call (void)rb_backtrace()' | lldb -p $(pgrep -nf ruby)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't call internal functions like that, internal functions expect things like frame, return value and so on ... don't' do it.

There is a [.gdbinit](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/.gdbinit) distributed with php, in it there is a function named [zbacktrace](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/.gdbinit#L557), you could port that to lldb.

Another thing you could do, which is likely easier, is just call the API function that generates a trace, but call it properly.

Here it is for GDB (PHP7):

```
define ztrace
    set $var = malloc(sizeof(zval))
    call zend_fetch_debug_backtrace($var, 0, 0, 0)
    call php_var_dump($var, 0)
    call _zval_ptr_dtor($var, 0, 0)
    call free($var)
end

document ztrace
    show a debug backtrace
end
```

And for LLDB (PHP7):

```
(lldb) expr zval $var;
(lldb) expr zend_fetch_debug_backtrace(&$var, 0, 0, 0)
(lldb) expr php_var_dump(&$var, 0)
(lldb) expr _zval_ptr_dtor(&$var, 0, 0)
```

Since you asked, LLDB for PHP5.6 (no-zts):

```
(lldb) expr zval *$zp = (zval*) malloc(sizeof(zval))
(lldb) expr zend_fetch_debug_backtrace($zp, 0, 0, 0)
(lldb) expr php_var_dump(&$zp, 0)
(lldb) expr _zval_ptr_dtor(&$zp, 0, 0)
(lldb) expr free($zp)
```

Answer (score 1):

I played a bit around with this and found out how it works:

```
echo 'call (void)zif_debug_print_backtrace(0)' | lldb -p $(pgrep -fn php)
```

For your example of above this will not print anything because there is no backtrace. But when you run a script like this:

```
php -r "function r(){sleep(1000);}r();"
```

Then the lldb command will cause the PHP process to output:

```
#0  r() called at [Command line code:1]
```

Voila. Unfortunately this also crashes the script.

It does work with `gdb`, though:

```
echo 'call zif_debug_print_backtrace(0,0,0,0,0)' | gdb -p $(pgrep -fn php)
```

when detaching the script continues to run. (tested on Debian with PHP 5.6.14 (DEBUG))

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tested and it still kills the original process, so it basically works the same way. Any chance that it won't kill the original process?

Comment: I don't think this can be avoided. PHP is single threaded, so as soon as you want to execute a command externally, you need to stop the script.

Comment: It works in Ruby: `ruby -e 'sleep 1000'`, and `echo 'call (void)rb_backtrace()' | lldb -p $(pgrep -nf ruby)`.

Comment: Already `echo detach | lldb -p $(pgrep -fn php)` kills the process.

Comment: Reported lldb bug in [here](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25123). My `gdb` doesn't work on OSX (wrong Mach), I'll check in VM soon.

Comment: Can you explain why we need these zeros?

Comment: tbh it is because of the message "Too few arguments in function call." if I use less arguments. It's also the same number of arguments as here: https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/GDB_with_PHP